# Improving wifi / mesh network in a split-level house

Tags: networking, wireless-networking, router, wireless-router

I've been having trouble with networking since I moved into an old split-level home, so I got a mesh network as recommended to me. Problem is, the mesh also has the same problems.

My house seems to consume wifi downstairs. It'll work okay for a few weeks then suddenly the downstairs mesh unit does this: I'll see the indicator on the unit flash red (TV goes out and the streaming apps start screaming at me about connectivity. If I'm gaming, forget about staying online) and my app says the unit has gone offline. The unit will come back online after a few minutes, telling me I have a connection speed of a snail, before going offline again. This goes on for about 2-3 days before things work normally again. Rebooting the mesh does not fix this. Sometimes I can fix it by rebooting the router, but if it were my ISP, the other mesh units would be having issues too.

**Setup:**

- House is a split level from the 60s. probably could survive nuclear fallout
- router is at the half level.
- upstairs has no wifi problems. Downstairs is a
  wifi black hole
- ISP: Comcast
- Mesh nodes: TPLink Deco x3. One in the
  back split level, one at the stairs on a shelf, one in the back of
  the house downstairs. The one that goes out is the last one
  [Here's a bad paint drawing](https://i.stack.imgur.com/BfedJ.png)

**What I've done:**

- swapped deco units to see if one was bad (nope. all are functioning until the issue crops up)
- Put the deco units high on a shelf (the farthest one still loses connectivity)

**Question?**

I'm sure it's the house construction that's doing it but is there anything that I can do to get full connectivity downstairs? Throwing more mesh units at it isn't helping. I have enough deco units to cover a house twice my size and reach wifi halfway down my street.

Comment: I do this with Ubiquiti Lite Access Points. I found ways to route Ethernet from the router to the AP location and this gives me high speed and good service. No black holes

Comment: Can you elaborate on how this routing is done?

Comment: I have closets in the house and can route Ethernet between floors via a corner in the closet - you need small holes through the flooring at discrete spots to allow the cable to run

Comment: We're renting this house and I'm not sure the landlady would appreciate little holes in the floor. However, I'll double check to see if maybe the previous tenants had done something like this. There are all sorts of cables in random places in this house. Would I hook the downstairs mesh unit up to this cable if I find cables?

Comment: You need the Ethernet to connect to your router one end and to the mesh the other end. That is at least how I hook up and for sure, there is more than one way to do this.

Comment: That would be a very long cable from one end of the house to the other, and I am definitely not drilling holes into the hardwood floor in the half level. I'll check and see if something runs under the house.

Comment: Ethernet can go 300 feet so length in a family home should not present an obstacle

Comment: Report back with a environmental scan, try **wifi analyzer** from the play store if you have a relatively new android. Maybe you have a layer of lead paint in this house? More than likely you can scan the channels, then pick a relatively free channel for them and these issues will disappear.

Comment: I hope there's not lead paint.... Well I downloaded the wifi analyzer with the best rating. It throws a lot of numbers at me but the channels I can see. I have a singular dead channel (sometimes the middle range goes out too). However, it seems that the deco system cannot change channels. The units are supposed to choose a good channel or so the documentation says. Is it possible the channel changes are causing the disconnects?

Comment: I spent the night attempting to play my game. I'd get massive lag spikes but the unit didn't turn red. But after a few seconds, everything would be fine again. For my games, I'm wired into the downstairs unit which I was told would mimic a wired network. I cannot play on wifi downstairs. The TV will stream most of the time though but it's closer to the center unit.

Comment: It looks like they try to find a non congested channel on power up. Try disconnecting them for 5 ten minutes, and see if the reconfigure for a different channel. Unfortunately it looks like these were meant to be able to run without user intervention.

Comment: That seems to be working so far. I have no idea if they've configured for a new channel, but I'm able to watch TV again. I hope that continues to work, though there is a worry that it'll happen again in a few weeks. But if this is the fix, so be it.